# Have Christians opposed "Good Luck" wishes?

Tags: biblical-basis

We have a great question about [whether luck exists](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2863/what-does-the-bible-say-about-luck).  My question is to what extent have Christians frowned upon wishing someone "good luck" in church tradition.  Has it been frowned upon as a pagan practice?

Comment: Comments on the question, anyone?

Comment: Interestingly, Presbyterians (from my experience) do not seem to be as aggressive about accurate expression concerning saying "good luck" et al. as some others, even though, as Calvinists, Divine sovereignty is a major doctrinal emphasis. I myself have some scruples on this (and a bit on conditioning statements about the future, cf. James 4:13-15), though such seems more motivated by a desire to be technically correct (or perhaps worse, using "God talk" at church to appear 'righteous') than a desire to glorify God.

Answer (score 6):

Yes in Word of Faith circles we are trained not to say good luck as there is no such thing as luck. We say other things like "I'm praying for you", "God bless" and "it will work out". The verse we go in relation to this like many others is Mark 11:22.

Comment: Good answer.  This is also true in many circles. I know Baptists that refuse to say "good luck" because God is in control, and to give credit to "luck" instead of Him leaves us thanking our luck instead of Him. In essence, stealing glory and honor that is due Him.

Comment: How do Word of Faith people deal with "unfortunately" or even "happy"/"happen"? In **modern** English these do not usually connote luck, but their previous use was based on concepts of luck. (In some cases there is a sense of chance in their modern use.) "I feel pleasure" seems a somewhat odd way of saying "I am happy" (odd can be good). Replacing, e.g., "happen" with "occur by mysterious providence" and "fortunately" with "by pleasant providence" seems more formal and peculiar (though perhaps fitting a thoughtful and "peculiar people").

Comment: Good information. Does that mean your denomination strictly belief in predestination?

Comment: @Mawia we do strictly believe in a form of predestination because it is a Bible word but not the Calvinist type.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton happily/happy/happen are all Bible words so they are fine and the word unfortunate is also a Bible word the word luck is only used in paraphrase translations and it has a negative connotation there as well.